# Notebook trackpad doesn't work on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: touchpad, acer

I have an Acer Aspire E 14, running Ubuntu 15.10 and my trackpad doesn’t respond. I tried disabling and enabling it through the keyboard shortcut (<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> on my computer), but that doesn’t seem to be the problem.

The mouse works fine, by the way.

Any help?

xinput:

```
    ⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB Optical Mouse                         id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN0501:00 04F3:3011 UNKNOWN             id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD WebCam                                 id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Acer WMI hotkeys
```

uname:

```
Linux nameUbuntu 4.2.0-34-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 10 22:13:01 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Also, I used Ubuntu before, on the same computer, and it worked.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Comment: Please add also output of `uname -a` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like kernel 4.2 does not support this touchpad.

You have some options to get it work.

First try to boot with Ubuntu 16.04 image LiveUSB. If touchpad works with it, it means that kernel 4.4 does support the touchpad.

It this case you have one of 3 options:

1. Install Ubuntu 14.04 and update kernel to 4.4 by

   ```
   sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial
   ```
2. Install Ubuntu 16.04 beta. It will be released in less than a month.
3. Install a mainline 4.4 kernel from Ubuntu mainline PPA.

Comment: Well, it used to work on the same computer with the 15.10, I'll see about the kernel. Thanks.

Comment: In this case try to boot with a previous kernel using grub. It may be some bug if it worked before. These touchpads should be supported by 4.2.

Comment: I'll try that too, when I get home. I'll try using the live DVD, it seems to work there, just to make sure. Thank you very much!!! I'll try and see if it works for me.

Comment: It's working now, I'll edit the topic. Thank you!!